# Script for searching for several samples from a dataset in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to search for a list of samples through a set of data, how do I write this automatically

For example, the data is in `/home/.../datasetname`, and I have samples: `bob 54`, `alice 55`, etc. I want to search through all the zipped files under `datasetname` and extract lines with `bob` and `54` and lines with `alice` and `55`.

When I do this for one sample I write:

```
zcat datasetname* | grep "bob" | grep "54"> ~/bob54.txt
```

When I do this for two samples I write:

```
zcat datasetname* | grep "bob" | grep "54"> ~/bob54.txt

zcat datasetname*| grep "alice" | grep "55">~/alice55.txt
```

I'd like to write code that automates this process for n samples.

I can be contacted directly at Talia.Kohen@gmail.com

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You can respond to me directly at Talia.Kohen@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the help of `awk` and a couple of pipes - not the most efficient way, but see if it is fast enough to solve your problem:

```
zcat datasetname* | awk '{print "echo '\''"$0"'"'"' >> "$1$2".txt"}' | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you want a script that search some fields in all the file inside a folder and stores the result in a file.

The following script takes three input variables: the folder, the first and the second field. I wrote the minimal set of commands, which means that there are no test on the number of arguments and so on.

```
#!/bin/bash

# folder to search for F1 and F2
DIR=$1
# fields to search
F1=$2
F2=$3

#for each file in the folder, search and store matching lines
filelist=$(ls -1 ${DIR})

for file in ${filelist}
    do 
        echo "searching $F1 && $F2 in $file"
        # search the two fields and store the line
        line=$(zcat $file | grep "$F1" | grep "$F2")
        # if line is not empty, append to file 
        if [ -n "$line" ] 
            then
                echo "$line" >> "$F1$F2".txt
        fi
    done
```

Comment: How do I pass the arguments $1, $2, $3 to the script?

Comment: They are the 1,2,3 arguments of the command line, if the name of the script is script.sh then: script.sh folder field1 field2

Answer (score 0):

Try awk

```
zcat datasetname* | awk '
    /bob/   && /54/  { print > "bob54.txt" }
    /alice/ && /55/  { print > "alice54.txt" }
'
```